# Not able to invoke finalize() method on different objects

Tags: java, eclipse, finalize

Not  able  to  call  finalize() method  on  different Object. I am  using  Eclipse  .

I  have created  object  of  StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder("abc");
sb.finalize(); // compile time error The method finalize() from the type Object is not visible
```

I have created  a  2 classes  Test and  MyTest with main  method  in each

```
  public class Test {

          public  static  void main throws Throwable(String [] args ){

                  Test t= new  Test();
                  t.finalize();    //ok no  error

                  MyTest mt= new MyTest();

                  mt.finalize() // compile time  error  The method finalize() from the type Object is not visible
          }
    }
```

I have some questions on  my mind:

1)  As  object  is  super class of all java  classes.finalize  method  must  be   available  because finalize method is protected. Then  why   eclipse  is giving  such error ?

2) Is this a bug in eclipse ?

please someone elaborate this concept in details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would take a look at the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29) for Object, you would notice that the method has a visibility of `protected` NOT `public`.

> The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package. [source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

With `protected` only classes within the same package or sub-classes are allowed to access the method anything else will result in a compiler error.

```
public class Test {

    public  static  void main throws Throwable(String [] args ){
        Test t= new  Test();
        t.finalize();    //ok no  error
    }
}
```

Here you are calling `finalize` from within the class `Test` and as such `finalize` is visible as `Test` is, implicitly, a subclass of `Object`.

```
public class Test {

    public  static  void main throws Throwable(String [] args ){

        MyTest mt= new MyTest();
        mt.finalize() // compile time  error  The method finalize() from the type Object is not visible
    }
}
```

Here you are calling the method on the class `MyTest` and as this isn't from within the same class nor from within the `java.lang` package the `finalize` method isn't visible, hence a compiler error.

Comment: And `Object` is at the root of the type hierarchy of every class...

Comment: The call to `MyTest` isn't from within `MyTest` but from test. Hence a compiler error. And I suspose the `Test` isn't in the `java.lang` hence `finalize` isn't visible.

Comment: I think you mean the call to `finalize()` and you're correct - I was trying to prompt you to *add that to the answer*!

Comment: See my extended answer.

Comment: I already have, it's much better :)

Comment: @M.Deinum got  it..protected  member  become private ...thanks

Comment: @M.Deinum won't `main throws Throwable(....)` give compiler error?

Answer (score 1):

`Object#finalize()` is not supposed to be invoked externally.

From the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29)

```
Called by the garbage collector on an object when garbage collection determines that there are no more references to the object. A subclass overrides the finalize method to dispose of system resources or to perform other cleanup.
```

Comment: that  i know..but if someone   tries  compiler  should   not throw any compile  time error.

Comment: See the comment from @Task below your question, it should resolve your query.